# How was "個" used in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, translation, words, usage

I'm currently in the middle of reading this one magazine feature, and I came across this sentence --

> " [...] 多くの方にも認めてもらえるような。**そのために、"個"　としての自分をもっともっと磨いていきたいですね。**”

I know that "個" is kanji for a generic counter, but I've never encountered it being used on its own in a sentence before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

「個{こ}」, in this context, means "***an individual (as an independent existence)***" as opposed to a member/component of a group or society.

Thus, 「"個"　としての自分{じぶん}をもっともっと磨{みが}いていきたい」 means:

"I wish to keep improving my skills as an individual"

or simply

"I wish to keep becoming a better person"

This 「個」 is quite often used when talking about oneself (or another person) in a philosophical manner.　「個人{こじん}」 would be a synonym even though 「個」 sounds more philosophical.

Comment: Ohh, I see! So it would be in this manner that 個人的 would mean "individualistic".

Answer (score 1):

In this case 個 represents 'an individual', as in:

> I want to be more individual.